# Salesforce Partner API Opportunity Won't Update

Tags: php, salesforce

Why won't this opportunity update?

I submit my php form, and my log shows a Success Response code for the correct Opportunity ID#.

Here is my code (I'm leaving off the Salesforce connection part):

```
$opfields = array(
    'Stage' => 'Closed Won',
    'IsClosed' => 'true');
$sObject = new Sobject();
$sObject->fields = $opfields;
$sObject->type = 'Opportunity';
$sObject->Id = $opid;

$response = $mySforceConnection->update($sObject);
```

My goal is to simply close this opportunity.
Thanks.

Comment: Correction: Despite Success code, viewing the record in Salesforce indicates the Opportunity is not closed.

Comment: I found 1 issue. Inside the array, the Field name for 'Stage' is actually 'StageName'. However, when testing again, I get this as my result ` [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 0061A0000117A1NQAU
            [success] => 1
        )
`

Comment: ^^ This seems right, but the opportunity does not update in salesforce.

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you find a way to get this to work?